# How can I use SPARQL regex to parse Wikitext and extract values from parameters in a Wikimedia Commons template?

Tags: regex, sparql, wikidata, wikitext, regex-recursion

[This query against the Wikidata SPARQL endpoint](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20*%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20BIND%20(URI(CONCAT(%27https%3A%2F%2Fcommons.wikimedia.org%2Fentity%2FM%27%2C%20%3Fpageid))%20AS%20%3Ffile)%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Amwapi%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Aapi%20%22Generator%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wikibase%3Aendpoint%20%22commons.wikimedia.org%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mwapi%3Agcmtitle%20%22Category%3A1930s%20photographs%20in%20Auckland%20Museum%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mwapi%3Agenerator%20%22categorymembers%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mwapi%3Agcmtype%20%22file%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mwapi%3Agcmlimit%20%2250%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mwapi%3Aprop%20%22revisions%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mwapi%3Arvslots%20%22main%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mwapi%3Arvprop%20%22content%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wikibase%3Alimit%20%22once%22.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ftitle%20wikibase%3AapiOutput%20mwapi%3Atitle.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fpageid%20wikibase%3AapiOutput%20mwapi%3Apageid.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcontent%20wikibase%3AapiOutput%20%27revisions%2Frev%2Fslots%2Fslot%2Ftext()%27.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D) returns the Wikitext content of the first 50 files in the Wikimedia Commons category "1930s photographs in Auckland Museum". For each file, I want to extract several pieces of data from that content.

Working with just one file, [File:("Ultimate" stall) (AM 79483-1).jpg](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20*%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Amwapi%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Aapi%20%22Generator%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wikibase%3Aendpoint%20%22commons.wikimedia.org%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mwapi%3Agenerator%20%22revisions%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mwapi%3Apageids%20%2264827585%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mwapi%3Agcmtype%20%22file%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mwapi%3Agcmlimit%20%221%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mwapi%3Aprop%20%22revisions%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mwapi%3Arvslots%20%22main%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mwapi%3Arvprop%20%22content%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wikibase%3Alimit%20%22once%22.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ftitle%20wikibase%3AapiOutput%20mwapi%3Atitle.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fpageid%20wikibase%3AapiOutput%20mwapi%3Apageid.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcontent%20wikibase%3AapiOutput%20%27revisions%2Frev%2Fslots%2Fslot%2Ftext()%27.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D), as an example, the content looks like this:

```
== {{int:filedesc}} ==
{{Artwork 
| description = {{en|1=At the equestrian show. A man stands in front of a stall selling radios.}} 
| title = ("Ultimate" stall) 
| artist = {{Creator:Tudor Washington Collins}} 
| date = 1938 
| place of creation = 
| source = {{Images from Auckland Museum|section=library|object=photography|id=79483}}
           [https://api.aucklandmuseum.com/id/media/p/806abf5c0952f972e56bc95fed841c5031bcb9ff Photo] 
| accession number = 79483 (object number) 
| object type = 
| technique = Silver gelatin dry plate 
| dimensions = 
| institution = {{Institution:Auckland War Memorial Museum}} 
| permission = This image has been released as "CCBY" by Auckland Museum. For details refer to the
               [[Commons:Batch_uploading/AucklandMuseumCCBY|Commons project page]]. 
| credit line = 
| notes = 
| other_versions = <gallery> ("Ultimate" stall) (AM 79483-2).jpg </gallery>
}}

== {{int:license-header}} ==
{{CC-BY-4.0|1=Auckland Museum}}
[[Category:Images uploaded by Fæ]] [[Category:1930s photographs in Auckland Museum]]
[[Category:Tudor Washington Collins]] [[Category:Radio in Auckland Museum]]
[[Category:Images from Auckland Museum]]
```

I'm interested in these 3 values in the `source` parameter. I've tried to parse this content with regex; this is the the first expression I wrote, which deals with the bulk of the Wikitext:

```
^(?>.+{{Images from Auckland Museum\|)(.*?)(?>}}.+)$
```

I [used regex101.com to write this](https://regex101.com/r/JrAhx8/1), and from what I can tell it says:

1. Find (and discard) everything up to the string `{{Images from Auckland Museum|`, including that string. (This was the most obvious delimiter I could think of).
2. Capture everything that occurs afterward.
3. Find (and discard) everything from the first occurrence of a pair of right curly brackets (`}}`) to the end.

This leaves only the portion I'm interested in:

```
section=library|object=photography|id=79483
```

So far, so good.

I then created [another regex101.com session to work on just that portion](https://regex101.com/r/fMwcsz/1/), with this expression:

```
(?>.*?\=)(.*)(?>.*?\|)(?>.*?\=)(.*)(?>.*?\|)(?>.*?\=)(.*)
```

From what I can tell, *this* expression says:

1. Find (and discard) everything up to, and including, the first `=`.
2. Capture everything after that, up to, but not including, the first `|`
   …and repeats three times, one for each capture group, giving me the three data points I want.

It seems to work:
[image: Regex101.com evaluation of the syntax "(?>.?=)(.)(?>.?|)(?>.?=)(.)(?>.?|)(?>.?=)(.)" against the string "section=library|object=photography|id=79483"]

**My questions are these:**

1. How can I combine these regular expressions? Simply slotting the second into the first in place of its `(.*?)` does not appear to work.
2. Given that [regex allows recursion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html), is there a better (i.e., more efficient) way to write the second expression? (Would the SPARQL endpoint/language allow this?)
3. Is there any way in the first expression to simply say, after obtaining the first capture group, something like, "I've got what I want; stop"—and would there be any efficiency gain in doing so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand why do you think you need recursion. Couldn't you just use `{{Images from Auckland Museum\|[^=]*=(.*?)\|[^=]*=(.*?)\|[^=]*=(.*?)}}`? See https://regex101.com/r/dGU208/1

Comment: @horcrux Wow, yep, thank you! That's perfect. I had no idea you could simply write bits of the string in like that at the start of the expression; I thought everything had to be in brackets to denote groups that you do or don't want to capture. Thank you very much!